# How to thru char into TextBox?

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have some TextBox on focus ( cursor is blinking on him ).
Now, from other usercontrol ( that contain buttons ) i want to send event that will insert char into the TextBox when pressing any of the buttons that are on the usercontrol.

This need to be without lose the focus from the TextBox ... ( blinking cursor on the TextBox )

How can i do it ? 
( i try to raise key down event - but its does not work )

Comment: You cannot click another button without losing focus from textbox. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: ok, the focus is not the main issue :) - i want to use the button like kind of virtual keyboard

Comment: This is kind of virtual keyboard that contain 5 button ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
And each of them need to be added as char into the TextBox. The 'Virtual keyboard' is a userControl that exist in the same window with 2 textBox. I know witch of those two textBox are in focus - so i know to whom i need to send the event.
But i still don't know how to send the event ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your buttons to be not focusable (Focusable = false).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use this virtual keyboard with other applications, or is it something that's only going on in your application? Beyond that, if it is only your application, do you only ever want to insert characters into one particular `TextBox`, or potentially any `TextBox`?

If it's a virtual keyboard intended to work with any application, then you'll want to use a Win32 API method like [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx). `WinForms` has an extremely easy interface for [using SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

If it only ever needs to add characters to the one `TextBox`, then it's much more easy to modify the `TextBox`'s `Text` property rather than trying to raise events on it to get the desired behavior. There's a `CaretIndex` property that will tell you where to insert the character. Beyond that, it's simple string concatenation.

Comment: But the problem is that i need to move the cursor forward and back in and if i just change the text of the TextBox then this is not what happened.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="MainTextBox" />
            <Button Content="A"
                    Focusable="False"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="B"
                    Focusable="False"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="C"
                    Focusable="False"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="D"
                    Focusable="False"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="E"
                    Focusable="False"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainTextBox.Text += (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = button.Content as string;
textbox.SelectedText = text;
textbox.SelectionLength = 0;    // removing selection from inserted text
textbox.SelectionStart += text.Length;
```

This will insert button content at cursor position (and replace selected text) - the same as user inputted it from keyboard.
PS. if `textbox` is unknown, it may be found with

```
var textbox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(FocusManager.GetFocusScope(this)) as TextBox;
```

Instead of `FocusManager.GetFocusScope(this)` you may put `window`.

If you need it not only for textboxes - WinAPI functions should help. See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput